# Generar schemas correctamente

Tags: javascript, next.js, json-schema

Tengo una aplicacion en Next.js 14 y quiero generar schemas para el SEO.
Tengo este componente que genera correctamente los schemas

```
const JsonLdBreadcrumbComponent: React.FC<JsonLdBreadcrumbComponentProps> = ({
  pageSlug = "",
}) => {
  if (!pageSlug) return null;
  
  try {
    const breadcrumbSchema = createBreadcrumbSchema(pageSlug);
    const scriptBody = JSON.stringify(breadcrumbSchema);

    return (
      <Script
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: scriptBody }}
        strategy="beforeInteractive"
        id="JsonLdBreadcrumbComponent"
        type="application/ld+json"
      />
    );
  } catch (error) {
    return null;
  }
};
```

Y tengo varias formas de llamar al componente, puedo hacerlo desde _app.tsx (de esa forma puedo generarlo dinamicamente para todas las paginas que tengan `pageSlug`), puedo hacerlo desde la propia pagina donde quiero el schema (de esta manera tengo que llamar el componente desde cada una de las paginas de mi aplicacion), etc.

En todas funciona correctamente siempre y cuando yo use `strategy="beforeInteractive"` en el Script. El problema es que su uso me genera un warning.

> `next/script`'s `beforeInteractive` strategy should not be used
> outside of `pages/_document.js`. See:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-before-interactive-script-outside-document

Si yo dejo elimino strategy, o si uso cualquier otra strategy, el schema no existe en mi `view source code`.
Si llamo al componente desde el head que se encuentra en `_document.tsx` tampoco existe.
La unica forma en la que funciona es como lo estoy haciendo ahora, pero no puedo evitar ese warning y no quisiera solucionarlo agregando la linea `// eslint-disable-next-line @next/next/no-before-interactive-script-outside-document` (al menos quisiera saber qué está pasando y si es conveniente quitar este warning asi)

Comment: Lo raro es que si uso es `script` tradicional de html funciona perfecto, pero cuando uso `Script` de next.js no funciona.